# Why is the real part of $\frac{1+z}{|1+z|}$ greater than zero ($z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z| = 1$, $z\neq -1$)?

Tags: complex-numbers

I seem to be unable to wrap my head around this. We are given a complex number $z$ with $|z| = 1$ and $z \neq -1$. One has to proof that one of its square roots is
$$ w = \frac{1+z}{|1+z|}.$$
That part was not difficult, you just have to show $w^2 = z$. However, the second part of the question asks me to show why the real part of $w$ positive. The provided solutions suggest the following:
$$\mathrm{Re}(w) = \frac{1+x}{|1+z|} > 0\quad \text{because $x \neq -1$}.$$
I don't really get why this is the case. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: The real part of $z$, which I guess you are denoting $x$,must satisfy $-1≤x≤1$ since $1=|z|^2≥x^2$. Since $z\neq -1$ we must have $-1<x≤1$.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Since $z$ has modulus $1$ and $z \neq -1$, $-1 < \mathfrak{Re}(z) \le 1$, so $0 < \mathfrak{Re}(z+1) \le 2$. Dividing by the positive number $|1+z|$ gives $\mathfrak{Re}(w) > 0$.